# USB Tethering option (to share internet connection with PC) is greyed out

Tags: android-12, usb-tethering, oneplus

> Most probably these question+answer will be deleted as duplicates, so please **do not vote here**. But if the answer is useful - add your upvote here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/252613/251126 in order to bubble a good (my hehe) answer there

For years I used my phone as a backup connection to the internet (and you know - airports...)

Today I connected my phone to the laptop with my factory-default cable and tried to enable tethering - but the <kbd>USB Tethering</kbd> button in the menu was disabled.

How to make it enabled?

---

I checked the cable (several), and I use one that does the trick with another phone.

Recently I updated Android to v12

Answer (score 8):

> Most probably these question+answer will be deleted as duplicates, so please **do not vote here**. But if the answer is useful - add your upvote here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/252613/251126 in order to bubble a good (my hehe) answer there

So it turned out that I needed to dance around the phone a little.

### 1 enable "Developer options"

In two words: <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>About device</kbd> > <kbd>Version</kbd> and here tap "Build number" several times.

Or google this: `android YOURBRAND enable Developer options`

### 2 reset default USB settings

<kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>System settings</kbd> (at the bottom) > <kbd>Developer options</kbd> > **<kbd>Default USB configuration</kbd>**

I had *"No data transfer"* there, I changed it to **"USB Tethering"**

And also check the neighbor menu item **<kbd>Select USB configuration</kbd>**, my default value was *"Charging"*, so I changed it to **"RNDIS (USB Ethernet)"**

Now disconnect-connect the cable, and it should work